# Does Hamas have 500 km of tunnels under Gaza?

Tags: technology, hamas, gaza

In 2021, Hamas leader [said](https://www.jpost.com/breaking-news/hamass-sinwar-we-have-10000-terrorists-within-israel-669265) "We have 500 km of tunnels in Gaza".
The reason I find it dubious is due to speed of digging.
Accodring to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_boring_machine), a tunnel boring machine can dig in rock in a speed of about 700 m/week, and in soil (which is more relevant to Gaza strip) about 200 m/week. So, to dig 500 km, they would need 50 years work of tunnel boring machines. But at that time, they had only ruled the Gaza strip for 14 years, and it is not clear they had the most advanced digging technology.

QUESTIONS:

- Is it possible, with technology available in Gaza, to dig 500 km of tunnels in 16 years?
- Is there other evidence, not based on Hamas sources, that the length of tunnels under Gaza is anywhere near 500 km?

Comment: You assume that the tunnel is a linear tunnel with two ends. This is not. This is a complex multipath tunnel. So many workers can dig in one of it.

Comment: "Is there other evidence, not based on Hamas sources" What do you think an answer will look like? If we exclude Hamas sources, who is going to have empirical evidence of whether this is true?

Comment: @Oddthinking, perhaps IDF or US estimates based on intel.

Comment: @YouDontSay: Any reason to trust the IDF's estimates over Hamas ones? Both seem to have a incentive to play up the number.

Comment: @Oddthinking there may be indirect evidence, e.g. pictures of a large number of tunnel-digging equipment in Gaza, that can probably be used to dig long tunnels in a short time (making the reasonable assumption that this equipment does not stand idle). Also, maybe there is some X-ray-like technology that can detect tunnels from above the ground.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi, good point, the IDF has also released overhead imagery showing the concrete components of tunnel fortifications, that can also be used in an estimate

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi: I think you might be overly locked in on the idea that tunnels are only built with large equipment. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_tunnel_warfare_in_the_Gaza_Strip#:~:text=Hamas%20used%20electric%20or%20pneumatic,more%20durable%20level%20of%20clay.) cites sources suggesting jackhammers.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi The tunnels aren't through rock, so they are easy to dig, but need more support.  For comparison, El Teniente has 3000km of tunnels, through actual rock.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Teniente

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi "tunnels usually dug through sandy soil" https://www.timesofisrael.com/hamas-said-to-have-executed-dozens-of-tunnel-diggers/

Comment: @DavePhD so digging through soil is slower because of the support? [In El Teniente the digging started over 200 years ago]

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi In soil, you can just use a pit and shovel, but Hamas is lining the sides and roof with concrete.  Yes, I think the concrete lining is the rate limiting factor.    The link I posted above says a tunnel lead advances 4-5 meters per day.  But you have to multiply by the number of entrances.  They can dig in a least one direction from each of hundreds or thousands of entrances.

Comment: They aren't talking tunnels like you'd use a tunnel boring machine for.  They are talking tunnels that can be anything from a crawlway just barely big enough for a person to squeeze through to larger hollows you could use as storage or gathering places.  More like the escape tunnels prisoners dig to get out of prison than a tunnel through a mountain.

Comment: TBMs are large. We're talking about much narrower tunnels here if one looks at some videos.

Comment: @DavePhD: El_Teniente ... yea but in 200 years.

Comment: As a ballpark (by factor of 5 say), it doesn't seem implausible given the Viet Cong tunnels https://www.usace.army.mil/About/History/Historical-Vignettes/Military-Construction-Combat/062-Viet-Cong-Tunnels/#:~:text=Some%20complexes%20ranged%20up%20to,design%20features%20in%20their%20tunnels. They also didn't have a lot of equipment. I'm not sure if this is good enough for an answer, given that the US estimated those. @Oddthinking what do you think?

Comment: Also [Vịnh Mốc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%E1%BB%8Bnh_M%E1%BB%91c_) tunnels were dug through limestone with hand tools, but these are much shorter: 2km, and took 2 years for the locals.

Comment: @Oddthinking: related then: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56381/does-vietnam-have-120-km-of-tunnels-preserved-from-the-viet-cong-era

Comment: @Fizz: It is hard to say if the stories about the Gaza tunnels have been inspired by the Viet Cong tunnels, so it wouldn't make a very definitive answer [that the Gaza tunnels actually exist, rather than a myth exaggerated in the fog of war], but maybe it would address the "TBM" misunderstanding.

Comment: There are two very important factors that you seem to ignore. They didn't use specialized tunnel boring machines, they used people. Some with hand tools, some with power tools and some with the help of explosives. More over, they don't have a single tunnel with 500km length, they have many small tunnels. In several disconnected systems. So they are not limited to a single tunnel but can work on all their tunnels in parallel.

Answer (score 4):

I made some research trying to find all estimates of Hamas'
tunnels. This table summarizes it:<sup>1</sup>

| Length | Depth | Year | Citation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 65 feet (20 m) | 2014 | no cite |
| 500 km |  | 2021 | Yahya Sinwar[1](https://www.jpost.com/breaking-news/hamass-sinwar-we-have-10000-terrorists-within-israel-669265) |
| 300 km |  | 2021 | "Israeli army"[2](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/11/13/very-risky-israel-faces-months-long-campaign-against-hamas-gaza-tunnels) |
| 300 miles (500 km) |  | 2021 | "Israeli military"[3](https://www.npr.org/2021/06/04/1003387937/civilians-paid-a-steep-price-for-destroyed-tunnels-in-israeli-hamas-conflict) |
|  | 15 - 60 m | 2023 | "experts"[2](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/11/13/very-risky-israel-faces-months-long-campaign-against-hamas-gaza-tunnels) |
| 200 miles (300 km) |  | 2023 | "reports"[4](https://www.wilsoncenter.org/blog-post/hamas-and-gazan-tunnels) |
|  | 200 feet (60 m) | 2023 | "Some Israeli military experts"[4](https://www.wilsoncenter.org/blog-post/hamas-and-gazan-tunnels) |
| 300 miles (500 km) |  | 2023 | "Hamas claims"[5](https://www.npr.org/2023/11/02/1210087629/the-hamas-tunnels-a-wildcard-in-the-gaza-fighting) |
| 500 km |  | 2023 | "Hamas meanwhile claimed"[6](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-67097124) |
|  | 30 m | 2023 | "are believed to be"[6](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-67097124) |
|  | 45 m | 2023 | "There are claims"[7](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/oct/28/a-spiders-web-of-tunnels-inside-gazas-underground-network-being-targeted-by-israel) |
| 500 km | 70 m | 2023 | "is thought to be"[8](https://www.dw.com/en/what-to-know-about-hamas-tunnels/a-67164646) |
| 60 miles (100 km) |  | 2023 | "the army previously estimated"[9](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/12/17/world/middleeast/hamas-tunnels-gaza-israel-war.html) |
| 250 miles (400 km) |  | 2023 | "the army previously estimated"[9](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/12/17/world/middleeast/hamas-tunnels-gaza-israel-war.html) |
| 350-450 miles (500-700 km) |  | 2024 | "Senior Israeli defense officials"[10](https://www.timesofisrael.com/gaza-tunnels-stretch-at-least-350-miles-far-longer-than-past-estimate-report/) |

In brackets I have converted the estimates to SI units and rounded to
one significant digit. Some sources estimate average or maximum depth
and others estimate total length. The source column shows to whom the
secondary source (the article itself) credits the figure to. For
example, the article [‘Very risky’: Israel faces months-long campaign
against Hamas Gaza
tunnels](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/11/13/very-risky-israel-faces-months-long-campaign-against-hamas-gaza-tunnels)
cites "*experts* estimating a depth between a range of 15 to 60
metres", but doesn't specify who those experts are. Note that both
Israel and Palestine uses the SI units which, potentially, could be
of concern. A journalist in a hurry might not notice that the
length is in *kilometers* and not *miles*. Or a "helpful" source might
convert a figure given in kilometers to miles when speaking to an
journalist and not perform the conversion correctly.

There is a lack of authoritative sources. The secondary source either
uses passive language ("is thought to be"), indicating that the
journalist just "googled it", or cites unnamed experts, or cites the
leader of Hamas Yahya Sinwar who in 2021 claimed that [Hamas possessed
500 km of
tunnels](https://www.jpost.com/breaking-news/hamass-sinwar-we-have-10000-terrorists-within-israel-669265).

Of note are the three estimates following Israel's 2023 invasion of
Gaza. Logically, the more time the Israeli army spends in Gaza the
more accurate its estimates of Hamas' tunnel network should become
(assuming that the Israeli army doesn't deliberately lie to
media). The first two of these comes from an December 17, 2023 [New
York Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/12/17/world/middleeast/hamas-tunnels-gaza-israel-war.html):

> Two military officials interviewed after the tour say that recently
> gathered intelligence indicated that Israel has grossly
> underestimated the size of the underground network. The system,
> which the army previously estimated was about 60 miles long, is now
> believed to be closer to 250 miles long, they said.

This is the only source for the "60 miles" estimate. My guess is that
the journalist confused the figure with the well-reported figure of
the Israeli army *destroying* [60 miles of tunnels back in
2021](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/world-news/2023/10/13/israel-target-gaza-metro-hamas-tunnels-hiding-terrorists/). The latest estimate is from a [Times of Israel article](https://www.timesofisrael.com/gaza-tunnels-stretch-at-least-350-miles-far-longer-than-past-estimate-report/):

> Senior Israeli defense officials now assess that Hamas’s Gaza tunnel
> network is between 350 and 450 miles long, far longer than
> previously believed, according to a Tuesday report. The estimate
> reported by The New York Times is markedly higher than an Israel
> Defense Forces’ assessment last month that there are some 250 miles
> of Hamas tunnels under the Gaza Strip, and an astounding figure
> given the enclave is only some 140 square miles in total size.

Curiously, the cited New York Times article doesn't contain the
350-450 miles estimate, so it is unclear where it comes from. However,
it also cites an official Israeli army source that claims that there are
5,700 tunnel shafts, and that Hamas spent more than 6,000 tons of
concreete and 1,800 tons of steel to build the network.

A few articles mention tunnels that the Israeli army has found. In
December 2023, the Israeli army claimed that it had uncovered ["the
biggest Hamas tunnel yet"](https://www.timesofisrael.com/idf-uncovers-largest-ever-hamas-attack-tunnel-near-northern-gaza-border-crossing/). The tunnel was 4 kilometers (2.5
miles) long and 50 meters deep:

[image]

It stands to reason that most tunnel segments must be shorter than 4
kilometers. Whether this tunnel was the longest in the network or just
one of many long tunnels is of course unknown.

Here are my conclusions of the evidence. Feel free to draw your own:

- Unless you trust unnamed Israeli military sources or Yahya Sinwar's
  word, no credible evidence suggests that the total length of all
  Hamas tunnels approaches the hundreds of kilometers range. For
  comparison, Paris' metro is [214
  km-long](https://www.railway-technology.com/projects/paris-metro-france/) and its sewer system is [2,100 km-long](https://www.atlasobscura.com/places/paris-sewer-museum).
- Same goes for the depth. Deep tunnels face many technical
  difficulties such as groundwater infiltration, ventilation,
  lighting, and earth pressure. Gaza's soil is made of sediment of
  clay and sand so tunnels have to be reinforced with concrete to
  prevent them from collapsing. Deeper tunnels face more pressure and
  need more reinforcement.

1. I first wrote this answer in November 2023 and have updated it.

Comment: The Paris metro is a poor analogy, and feeds in to the OP's confusion about tunnel sizes. Paris also has [2,100 km  of sewers](https://www.atlasobscura.com/places/paris-sewer-museum), and [89 km of cooling water pipes](https://reasonstobecheerful.world/cooling-system-paris-seine-water-pipes). These tunnels are probably even more make-shift than those, given the conditions under which they were built.

Comment: In addition to what @Oddthinking said about not tunnels being the same, no one ever claimed that all of the tunnels are 60 meters deep. The claim is that some of them contain rooms or complexes at this depth, which are probably the most important rooms in the tunnel system. And that those tunnels have the needed tools to keep themselves, like oxygen and electricity generators. The Burj Khalifa is more than 800 meters tall, it doesn't mean that every building in Dubai is at that height and the building stands even though it's hard to maintain such a huge building.

Comment: The answer specifies that the depth estimate is for maximum or average tunnel depth. Not that *all* tunnels are necessarily that deep. However, depth is a factor as depth implies engineering challenges that may be hard for Hamas to overcome due to lack of advanced and heavy machinery due to Israel's blockade of the Gaza strip.