# Does Vietnam have 120 km of tunnels preserved from the Viet Cong era?

Tags: vietnam

It's widely reported that there were hundreds of kilometers of Viet Cong tunnels. However that may be hard to prove exactly, in retrospect, how long they were. OTOH a more recent [source](https://tuoitrenews.vn/news/politics/20221001/cuban-pm-visits-cu-chi-tunnels-in-ho-chi-minh-city/69351.html) claims that there *are* 120 km of *preserved* tunnels.

> More than 120 kilometers out of the 250 kilometers of the tunnels’ length has been preserved for tourism purposes.

A similar [claim](https://asiapioneertravel.com/blog/cu-chi-tunnels-guide/):

> The Cu Chi Tunnels, stretching all the way to the Cambodian frontier, once boasted an impressive length of nearly 250 kilometers. Out of this, 120 kilometers have been meticulously preserved and are now open to the public.

Can this claim be verified with contemporary/peace surveys?

FWTW, Wikipedia cites a [source](https://web.archive.org/web/20110107110800/http://www.cuchitunnel.org.vn/content/index.php?var=3&more=1&lan=1) for the 120 km figure... which doesn't actually give it. But it does give some area figures for the museum(s)/reservations. Which (after converting from hectares) seem to be only about 1-2 square km, in total. It's possible the tunnels have a high density, but this is inconclusive.

Comment: If someone can suggest additional tags...

Comment: There's a [2019 page](https://www.mumonthemove.com/visiting-the-cu-chi-tunnels-in-vietnam/) that says that only 100 meters are/were visitable by tourists [then], although that's not necessarily the same thing as much more not being preserved.

Comment: I found the same numbers on a [gov.vn page](https://vietnamtourism.gov.vn/post/12918), but they seem to have gotten that from [CNN](https://www.cnn.com/travel/article/underground-attractions/index.html), and it's not clear where they got the numbers from.

Comment: Most Vietnam websites e.g. [this](https://mia.vn/cam-nang-du-lich/dia-dao-cu-chi-12466) or [this (Indonesian)](https://www.traveloka.com/vi-vn/explore/destination/dia-dao-cu-chi/156462) claim that the tunnel is 250 km long.

Comment: Is the question specifically about tunnels kept for tourism? Tunnels may be preserved for other purposes, maybe for storage or routing pipes/cables. There's also the question of what "preserved" means - would fencing a tunnel off count as preserving it? It's also possible that 120 km may be preserved at particular a site but substantially less can be travelled through by tourists, since you wouldn't let tourists just wander unsupervised through 120 km of tunnels.

Comment: @StuartF: no, not specifically for tourists.